# header("content-type: image/jpg") not working on online server

Tags: php

Although this command works perfectly on my localhost, I don't know why it's not working on the online server. I have tried:

```
$sql = "SELECT photo FROM database WHERE userID = '$uID'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$imgData = $row['photo'];
ob_start();
header("content-type: image/jpg");
echo $imgData;
ob_end_flush();
```

but nothing happened! can you help me?

Comment: What's the problem? What happens?

Comment: _"but nothing happened!"_ Well, you haven't output anything. What are you expecting to get?

Comment: I'm sorry I did not put much code because the problem is that the server does not read the header line only. I have modified the code to make it more clear :)

Comment: Let you put ob_start on top of all code. May be you'll be using any output code before $sql variable! Also there is no need of ob_end_flush(), just remove it, it'll be used by default

Comment: Also tried this one but no result

Comment: Are you getting any data without header like some unreadable text?

Comment: You probably have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Check your apache server settings are the same and that your server has access to the files directory. Also make sure you don't block that file type in your htaccess or vhost settings.

Comment: not at all .. it's completely normal like this line is not existed

Comment: Also don't store photo's in the database. Instead store a path to a files directory. Much cleaner and doesn't bloat the database.

Comment: Actually the server does not belong to me so I have no control over its configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this code runs it means there is not problem with the header. There is another problem with your sql,etc.

```
<?php
/*$sql = "SELECT photo FROM database WHERE userID = '$uID'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$imgData = $row['photo'];*/
$imgData = file_get_contents('http://www.dummymag.com//media/img/dummy-logo.png');
ob_start();
header("content-type: image/jpg");
echo $imgData;
ob_end_flush();

?>
```

Comment: You are right! it worked with this way :)
So I guess my problem is in the online database!
Thank you so much for your help